# How can I use a variable inside expression() to make the y-axis label of a bar plot in R?

Tags: r, variables, expression, bar-chart, axis-labels

I want to make a bar plot with the y-axis label containing some units. I have used expression() to get them correctly formatted. If it's coded directly in the script, everything works properly. If I want to use a variable instead to enable automatisation, the label is not shown correctly. Is there a way to use a variable together with expression() inside or outside of barplot()?

To automatize the script I iterate through a bunch of text files and create many graphs in one go. To get the y-axis labels, the script reads a second text file containing the information. Of course it is not formatted as it should. Therefore I still need to use expression(). Hence, the actual y-axis label text (or part of it) is stored in a variable but if I replace the respective piece of code with the variable it does not show the proper label in the graph.

```
# 1) this works properly but i actually don't want to use it

    labelY <- expression(paste("Mn content [", µg,"*",mg^{-1},"DW]"))    

# 2) i want to replace "Mn content" by something else (e.g. "Fe
# content") with a variable 'varLabel' but it does not work

    labelY <- expression(paste(varLabel," [", µg,"*",mg^{-1},"DW]")) 

# 3) i tried to replace the whole label with a variable but this
# doesn't work either

    labelY <- expression(varLabel) 

# plot the graph ('dataplot' contains the actual data)

    daMightyPlot = barplot(dataplot, beside=T, legend.text=T,
        col=barColors, ylim=c(0,lim), ylab = labelY, names.arg=namesArg,
        cex.axis=1.0, cex.names = 1.0, font.lab = 1, cex.lab = 1.2
    )
```

As stated above, the manual y-axis label definition does work properly. However, when I want to use a variable to replace a part of the string (case 2), it shows something else as the y-axis label:

> $(variable) [µg*mg^-1 DW]

So it does not want to display the variable content but only shows the variable name. What I want is for example:

> Mn content [µg*mg^-1 DW]

... if "Mn content" is stored in the variable. The outcome is similar when I replace the whole expression inside expression() with a variable (case 3).

Does anyone have a solution? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bquote`:

```
labelY <- expression(paste("Mn content [", µg,"*",mg^{-1},"DW]"))  
plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.3, labelY)

varLabel <- "Fe content"
labelY <- bquote(paste(.(varLabel)," [", µg,"*",mg^{-1},"DW]")) 
text(0.5, 0.6, labelY)
```

Result:

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Btw. I would use `labelY <- bquote(.(varLabel) ~ group("[", "µg"~"mg"^{-1}~DW, "]"))`. It looks a bit nicer.

Comment: Woot! Very quick help. It works like a charm. Thank you!